# Issuing Inserts/Updates to Progress OpenEdge via ODBC

Tags: ssis, odbc, progress-database, ssis-2014

I'm attempting to build some ETL to integrate our SQL Server environment with a remotely hosted 3rd party app running Progress OpenEdge. I have a linked server to it set up in SQL Server 2014.

Selects are working well enough, though I find that using `openquery` is much, much faster than the simpler `select * from SERVER.DB.SCHEMA.TABLE` syntax.

I'm struggling with writes, however. I've found several references for valid update syntax for linked servers, but these all give permissions errors:

```
select * from openquery(SERVER,'update FOO.BAR set "COL" = 0 where "COL" = 1')

update fb set [COL] = 0
   from SERVER.DB.FOO.BAR fb
   where [COL] = 1

update openquery(SERVER,'select * from FOO.BAR where "COL" = 1')
       set [COL] = 0
```

This syntax is the only one I've found that works:

```
declare @script nvarchar(max) = N'update FOO.BAR set "COL" = 0 where "COL" = 1'
execute (@script) at SERVER
```

This works for both inserts and updates, but I can't see a way to load a set of data this way, because I can't reference my local tables.

In SSIS, an ODBC connection passes the connectivity test, but fails during initialization:

> Error: 0xC0014020 at Package1, Connection manager "SERVER": An ODBC error -1 has occurred.
>
> Error: 0xC0014009 at Package1, Connection manager "SERVER": There was an error trying to establish an Open
> Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.
>
> Error: 0x20F at Data Flow Task, ODBC Destination [2]: The
> AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager SERVER failed with error code 0xC0014009.  There may be
> error messages posted before this with more information on why the
> AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: ODBC Destination
> failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005.
>
> Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more
> component failed validation.
>
> Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task
> validation.

Ultimately, I'm searching for a better way to merge/upsert a set of data (anything from a few dozen rows to a couple hundred thousand) without resorting to using RPC to insert/update one row at a time.

Comment: FWIW, the openquery syntax generally gives better performance with filtered queries because it pushes the filter to the source system. The 4 part query can result in all the data being pulled back to SQL Server and *then* the filter is applied. Syntax for openquery may be a little wonky but I'll take that over the performance drag. Never mucked about with pushing updates though

Comment: `There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed` <- were there additional messages? `SELECT * FROM ssisdb.catalog.operation_messages AS OM WHERE OM.message_type = 120 AND OM.operation_id = @MyLastRun;`

Comment: I've been trying in both SSMS and SSIS. Edited to include full set of errors from SSIS (I'm not using the catalog yet--we skipped 2012, and not yet up to speed on 2014).

Answer (score 1):

Once you've identified which one you need, probably 32 bit version, you'd need to ensure your project is using the appropriate run-time. Right click on your project and select Properties and then navigate to the Debugging tab under the Configuration Properties. After inverting the Run64BitRuntime value, I assume your package will work from within SSDT.